Mother Pattern. Best practices. Typing
I have following classes:
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class VarCharType(str, ABC):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._validate_length(value)

    def _validate_length(self, value: str):
        if not self._min_length <= len(value) <= self._max_length:
            raise TypeError(f'Length must be between {self._min_length} and {self._max_length}')

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def _min_length(self) -> int:
        pass

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def _max_length(self) -> int:
        pass


class GivenName(VarCharType):
    _MIN_LENGTH = 1
    _MAX_LENGTH = 255

    @property
    def _min_length(self) -> int:
        return self._MIN_LENGTH

    @property
    def _max_length(self) -> int:
        return self._MAX_LENGTH


class FamilyName(VarCharType):
    ...


To test my code I decided to create random values of FamilyName and GivenName through a Mother pattern. Something like that:
class GivenNameMother:
    def random_max(self) -> GivenName:
        return GivenName(''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=255)))
    
    def random_min(self) -> GivenName:
        return GivenName(''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=1)))

class FamilyNameMother:
    def random_max(self) -> FamilyName:
        return FamilyName(''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=255)))
    
    def random_min(self) -> FamilyName:
        return FamilyName(''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=1)))


Previous implementation have several problems:

If GivenName changes Max or Min length I must change the Mother class. I have some doubts if it is a feature or a problem.
For each VarCharType children classes I need to create a mother class with more or less the same code. The problem is in some moment I want to test with utf-8 characters I should change all mother classes.

I tried several solutions but are very dirty and I do not like it.
What would be the best solution? It is a requirement avoiding typing with Any from typing package.
Thanks!

First off let me say, this is not meant to be a perfect solution.  You'll still need to figure out how exactly you'd like to share the information between the classes, but this should at least show you how you can have a generic NameMother that could still support good typing.
So a few notes:

I added a placeholder typing for the _MIN_LENGTH and _MAX_LENGTH to the class.  This is because _min_length and _max_length are setup to be instance methods and not static methods so they aren't accessible without an instance of the class.  If we make an instance, we have to pass in a value and not knowing the min or max, we'd potentially hit the `ValueError.
You could easily pull all 'config' --such as the random choices-- from the type class, not just the min/max.
These are leveraging python 3.11 syntaxes and constructs, some of the specifics may differ if you're on a older or newer version as the syntax around typings have evolved significantly over time.

import random
import string

from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


class VarCharType(str, ABC):
    _MIN_LENGTH: int
    _MAX_LENGTH: int

    def __init__(self, value: str) -> None:
        self._validate_length(value)

    def _validate_length(self, value: str) -> None:
        if not self._min_length <= len(value) <= self._max_length:
            raise TypeError(f'Length must be between {self._min_length} and {self._max_length}')

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def _min_length(self) -> int:
        pass

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def _max_length(self) -> int:
        pass


_T = TypeVar('_T', bound=VarCharType)


class NameMother(Generic[_T]):
    klass: type[_T]

    def __init__(self, klass: type[_T]) -> None:
        self.klass = klass

    def random_max(self) -> _T:
        return self.klass(''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=self.klass._MAX_LENGTH)))

    def random_min(self) -> _T:
        return self.klass(''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=self.klass._MIN_LENGTH)))


class GivenName(VarCharType):
    _MIN_LENGTH = 1
    _MAX_LENGTH = 255

    @property
    def _min_length(self) -> int:
        return self._MIN_LENGTH

    @property
    def _max_length(self) -> int:
        return self._MAX_LENGTH


given_name_mother = NameMother(GivenName)
print(given_name_mother.random_max())
print(given_name_mother.random_min())

Output:
IESFIVCVYRPDBGQWQWWVVRHXQUSUJVDCUSFPEAFOPGENUWLQRSYDFJCUEVMFJXQVNJXFWQJWOLYVPBFROLHXZCIMYDYUGXBJNIYLZTVLWUBNWRLHDOGHJFHIQJSBHZPMPBSKXOJLGNLAKQVWGHKUTGQIEXCMCAKBGSBCZTCKHKGQXPLITMKHWHBQRAJBDYOVBGETGGUXVPNXLQGOGZGAPWTZZFEUXRFSNRCATRFGQBVYMDNNPZSXJOEZMSEYHDR
J

